# Cyclic Groups - Existence of the identity

Tags: group-theory

> How is it claimed that the identity of a cyclic group $G$ with generator 'a' can be written in the form of $e = a^m$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

A proof for a subgroup of $G$ being in itself cyclic claims that any element in the subgroup can be written in the the form $a ^ n$ and assume that $n > 0.$ Furthermore the Well Ordering principle is used to claim the existence of $m$ above.

The definition of a cyclic group only requires its members be able to be raised to any power of the generator.

Suppose g is an element of $G$. Then $g = a ^ i$ where $i < 0$. How can I proceed to prove that g can be written in the form of a positive power of $a$?

Comment: Your question is "how can all elements of a cyclic group be written as a generator to a positive power"? Much of your discussion is obscuring or distracting. First off, you are talking about a *finite* cyclic group - the result does not hold for the infinite cyclic group - and second, do you have any experience or familiarity with cyclic groups at all? In particular, do you have any intuition or understanding as to why they are *called* "cyclic" in the first place? It's because the powers *cycle* (hint hint, wink wink) ...

Comment: Pardon my idiocy. I am forced to learn a bit of introductory group theory as part of a conclusion to a Number Theory course believe it or not. I's still in my first semester in College. Sure the powers cycle. It's intuitive. But how can I get there with some rigor from the definition of a cyclic group.

Comment: Check out theorem 4.3 in page 71. Author claims n > 0 can be assumed and the existence of an 'm'.. How so ?? http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20130816.pdf

Comment: If the powers cycle, then every power is equivalent to a finite selection of powers, in particular the first $n$ positive ones. Translate that into rigorous argument.

Answer (score 2):

First I assume that we're talking about a *finite* cyclic group.  The group $(\mathbb Z, +)$ is an example of what some people would call an infinite cyclic group and it is certainly not true that $n\cdot 1 = 0$ for some $n > 0$ (note everything is translated into additive notation in that example, but I switch back to multiplicative notation below).

Now assume the group is finite cyclic and generated by $a$.  Look at the sequence $(a, a^2, a^3, a^4, \ldots)$.  As the group is finite this sequence must repeat at some point, say $a^n = a^m$ for some $n > m$.  Now multiply both sides by $a^{-m}$ to get $a^{n - m} = 1$ and $n - m > 0$.

Comment: Right one more stupid question.. The issue's sorted for finite groups. But if you guys can care to waste some time could you please check out the proof in the link pasted above. It just proves that a subgroup of a cyclic group is in itself cyclic. But no restriction is made for finite groups. Is it still applicable??

Comment: Yes, subgroups of infinite cyclic groups are cyclic (in fact, they are infinite cyclic).

Comment: Righto Jim and anon, Thanks a lot people.. Much appreciated..